# Plasma Desktop Notes - Disable them

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, stickynotes

I run Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Ubuntu w/ KDE).  I also use middle-click for pasting, so I do not want to eliminate that from my middle mouse butting.

The issue is that middle-click on the desktop creates one of those Crom-forsaken sticky notes.  I troied going into Discover and removing that Notes widget package, but it wants to uninstall all of the Plasma Desktop widget packages.  So the question is...

"How do I completely disable those crappy sticky-notes, without removing the plasma desktop widget packages, or disabling "paste" on my middle-click?

Comment: Also: how to remove a sticky note from the desktop? There's a preferences menu button on the note, and right-click reveals a menu of edit commands. I removed one but I'm stuck with another ... ?! Update: click on the (invisible) (bottom?) border of the note to get the remove notes option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting for that!

- Right click on your desktop and choose "**Configure Desktop...**"
- Click the "**Mouse Actions**" tab.
- Next to "**Middle-Button**", use the drop down menu to select a different action.  You can also click the `-` button to remove the action.

This setting only affects the middle mouse button behavior when you click on your desktop, so it does not affect your ability to use the middle mouse button to paste when using applications.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me.  I thought it was disabling the paste functionality globally.  +1 for learning.  :)